# Best way to temporarily persist a global flash message alert in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

If within a controller I want to set a global variable (a admin action) will that have effect across all instances of that same application across heroku dynos?

maybe there is a better tool
use case, I want to set a single global message Flash message across the application in emergencies and rare occasions. I didn't think it should warrant a migration/model but I want it to persist on a temporary basis until i remove it or reset the application.

$alert = "We are aware of a bug with email notifications and expect fix in 2 hours"

I have a controller that has simple new/create/delete action for this particular use.

Comment: For 'one-off' notifications, you can use the [paul_revere](http://www.plugingeek.com/repos/thoughtbot/paul_revere) gem and take inspiration from this [RailsCast on side-wide announcements](http://railscasts.com/episodes/103-site-wide-announcements-revised).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you really need persistent messages here that are not bound to a single user/session.

Create a model `SiteMessage` with at least a field `message`. Store the global messages in this table. Every request, check if there are messages in the table. If so, show them. Delete the message from the table when they are not needed anymore.

Comment: how about using the heroku config environment variables as a persist across all apps?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku dynos do not share state, so you'll have to persist it in some shared resource (Redis, database, etc.).